# Saving movie file in a particular folder -android-

Tags: java, android, download, android-sdcard

I have an android code for download videos from YouTube it works fine but it save the video file inside the application folder and i can not find the video in "Video" public folder

```
public void onNext(String downloadUrl) {
    dismissWaitDialog();

    String fileName = fmtStreamMap.title + "." + fmtStreamMap.extension;
    /*Added By Morad*/
    if (fmtStreamMap.extension.contains("mp3")) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(downloadUrl);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(MainActivity.this,Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC, fileName);
        downloadManager.enqueue(request);
    } else {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(downloadUrl);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(MainActivity.this,DIRECTORY_MOVIES, fileName);
        //request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(DIRECTORY_MOVIES, fileName);
        downloadManager.enqueue(request);
    }
}
```

I used `request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(DIRECTORY_MOVIES, fileName);` but it didn't not work.

Comment: first you can check the folder exist, if folder not exist then create folder after start download.

Comment: can you modify my code,,, please

Comment: what is the value of `downloadUrl` . use `Log.i()` to print it, your file should be stored in that path

Answer (score 1):

```
  public void onNext(String downloadUrl)
     {
         dismissWaitDialog();

         String fileName = fmtStreamMap.title + "." + fmtStreamMap.extension;

           /*Added By Morad*/

            if (fmtStreamMap.extension.contains("mp3")){
                check_folder(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(downloadUrl);
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
                request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(MainActivity.this,Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC, fileName);
                downloadManager.enqueue(request);
             }else{
                check_folder(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES); 
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(downloadUrl);
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
                request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(MainActivity.this,DIRECTORY_MOVIES, fileName);
                //request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(DIRECTORY_MOVIES, fileName);
                downloadManager.enqueue(request);
              }

    }


  public void check_folder(String path)
    {
        File file=new File(path);

        if(!file.exists())
        {
            file.mkdir();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It does not work,,,,, also when i user :Method request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(DIRECTORY_MOVIES, fileName); the application show Error Message!!!